React server and client on Ubuntu VM
So I have a React project that I made that includes server side and client side code. Each one has their own package.json file and node modules folder. To run this app locally I open 2 terminals and run node index.js on the server side and npm start on the client side. Then I navigate to localhost:3000 and boom, I have my react app.
I'm not sure if this changes things, but I also created a start.bat file so I could create a desktop shortcut to run the whole thing, but this just automates the two terminals and does the same thing. Here is my start.bat file:
@echo off

REM Start the server
start cmd /k "cd server && node index.js"

REM Wait for a few seconds to ensure the server is up and running
timeout /t 5

REM Start the client
start cmd /c "cd client && npm start"

REM Start the React app
start chrome --app=http://localhost:3000

My issue now is I need to move my react project to an Ubuntu 24.04 server where my production database is. I have the project on it, but now how do I run it? I only have one terminal interface available to me for this server. I would like to run it from another vm ideally, but I'll take tips on any way to run it.
I tried opening my start.bat file to run it from my one command line interface, but running start.bat in the folder it's in did not work (command not found).
I also found this: Deploying Client and Server to the same VM but they suggest running server side locally and I don't want to do this. I want my client side and server side code to run together on my production Ubuntu server. Is this possible or am I taking the wrong approach?
Thank you for any direction!

I'm still not sure how to run my project for development on this server, but I was able to host it for production and I'll figure out how to get the database hooked up this way. The way I hosted it for production is I installed nginx on my ubuntu server, then I ran npm run build on my client side code, finally I moved all the files in my build folder into the folder etc/nginx/sites-enabled. After doing this I just navigated to the ip address of my Ubuntu server and there is my app!
One thing I ran into while doing this was that Apache was running on port 80. I had to kill it using the command sudo killall apache2 to free up that port for nginx.
Hope this helps someone!
